# android.app.Person, or short uri to Contact

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I've got an `android.app.Person` object, which has an `uri` in the form `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r7-4E3A424614382A2443324C/8`. How do I convert this info into a `Contact`? Preferably via https://vestrel00.github.io/contacts-android/ - in a pinch, regular contacts API works too.